# Scheme; Error Holes in a Macro List

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp

So for a college assignment we've been asked to work with macros and I'm finding it hard to understand how to implement code in scheme (we went from reversing a string to building an interpreter in one lecture).

```
(define macro-alist
  `((and ,(λ (e)
            (let ((forms (cdr e)))
              (cond ((null? forms) '#t)
                    ((null? (cdr forms)) (car forms))
                    (else `(if ,(car forms) (and ,@(cdr forms)) #f))))))
    ;(or ,error)
    ;(let ,error)
    ;(cond ,error)
    (if ,(λ (e) (let ((guard (cadr e))
                      (then-part (caddr e))
                      (else-part (cadddr e)))
                  `((%if ,guard (λ () ,then-part) (λ () ,else-part))))))
    ))
```

We were asked to 'fill in the error holds in macro-alist' for the weekend and I'm finding it difficult.
I found some resources and combining them with my own brief knowledge I have :

```
`((or ,(lambda (e)
             (and (list-strictly-longer-than? e 0)
                  (equal? (list-ref e 0) 'or)
                  (letrec ([visit (lambda (i)
                                    (if(null? i)
                                       #t
                                       (and (is-exression? (car i))
                                            (visit (cdr i)))))])
                    (visit (cdr e)))))))
`((let ,(lambda (e)
          (and (proper-list-of-given-length? e 3)
               (equal? (car e) 'let)
               (list? (cadr e))
               (is-expression? (list-ref e 2))
               (lectrec ([visit (trace-lambda visit (i a)
                                              (if(null? i)
                                                 #t
                                                 (and (proper-list-of-given-length? (car i) 2)
                                                      (is-identifier? (caar i))
                                                      (is-expression? (cadar i))
                                                      (not (member (caar i) a))
                                                      (visit (cdr i) (cons (caar i) a)))))])
                        (visit (cadr e) '()))))))
`((cond ,(lambda (e)
           (and (list-strictly-longer-than? e 1)
                (equal? (car v) 'cond)
                (lectrec ([visit (lambda (i)
                                   (if (null? (cdr i))
                                       (is-else-clause? (car i))
                                       (if (pair? (cdr i))
                                           (and (cond? (car i))
                                                (visit (cdr i))))))])
                         (visit (cdr e)))))))
```

For or, let and cond. I'm wondering if these are correct or if I'm close. I don't understand much about macros or scheme in general so some information/help on what to do would be appreciated.

Comment: The "or case" should look almost exactly like the "and case". You don't need to check the first element of the list, it's going to be used to select one of these functions. You should not do any evaluation here, you should just return an expression that's equivalent to each macro.

Comment: Rather than follow your code in details: can you write the intended expansions of `(or)`, `(or e)`, `(or e1 e2)`, `(or e1 e2 e3)` (and similar for the other constructs) then it will be simpler for the readers to tell you whether your strategy is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of `and`:

```
(define expand-and
  (λ (e)
    (let ((forms (cdr e)))
      (cond ((null? forms) '#t)
            ((null? (cdr forms)) (car forms))
            (else `(if ,(car forms) (and ,@(cdr forms)) #f))))))


(expand-and '(and))     ; ==> #t
(expand-and '(and a))   ; ==> a
(expand-and '(and a b)) ; ==> (if a (and b) #f)
```

I notice two things. It doesn't really double check that the first element is `and` or if it's a list. Perhaps the interpreter doesn't use this unless it has checked this already?

Secondly it doesn't seem like you need to expand everything. As you see you might end up with some code + `and` with fewer arguments. No need for recursion since the evaluator will do that for you.

I think you are *overthinking* it. For `or` it should be very similar:

```
(expand-or '(or))        ; ==> #f
(expand-and '(or a b c)) ; ==> (let ((unique-var a)) (if unique-var unique-var (or b c)))
```

The let binding prevents double evaluation of `a` but if you have no side effects you might just rewrite it to `(if a a (or b))`. As with `and` `or` might expand to use `or` with fewer arguments than the original. This trick you can do with `cond` as well:

```
(cond (a b c)
      ...) ; ==>

(if a
    (begin b c)
    (cond ...))
```

`let` does not need this since it's perhaps the simplest one if you grasp `map`:

```
(let ((a x) (c y))
  body ...) ; ==>

((lambda (a c) body ...) x y)
```

[The report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs.html) has [examples of how the macros for these are made](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-16.html#node_chap_B), but they might not be the simplest to rewrite to functions that takes code as structure like your interpeter. However using the report to understand the forms would perhaps worked just as well as posting a question here on SO.